# Finding Connected Components

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to find connected components of a Directed Acyclic Graph using a set of nodes. What would be the most efficient way to solve this problem?

> **Connected Component**: If one of the nodes is a predecessor or
>   successors of another node, they are in the same connected component.

For example, let's say I have the following graph and `vector = [2,4,5,6,3]`. For this vector, there are two connected component as below.

```
C1 = [2,4,5,6]
C2 = [3]
```

[image]

My solution:

- Sort the nodes using their depth value
- Pick a node
- Check the other nodes if they are successors or not. If so, keep
  looking. If not, stop and go to step 2.

What do you think?

Comment: Sort the nodes using their depth value? In what order?
Connected Components? Do you mean strongly connected components or any connected components?

Comment: I mean any connected components. I will be able to pick the node at the top of the graph by sorting them using their depth value. @shole

Comment: so say i have 3 nodes and two edges 1-->2 & 1-->3,  {1,2,3} is a connected component ?

Comment: @shole I added an example.

Comment: I don't understand the example.

Comment: I forgot one of the nodes, check again. @G.Bach

Comment: Don't see what changed, and can't derive what definition of when two vertices are considered to be in the same connected component you have in mind.

Comment: If one of the nodes is a predecessor or successors of another node, they are in the same connected component. @G.Bach

Comment: What do you mean by "connected component"? Normally a connected component would be a maximal subgraph with a path between any pair of vertices, but I think you have your own definition.

Comment: Under the definition you've just added, why do 1 and 7 not appear in any "connected component"? Why are there two "connected components" and not just one?

Comment: Because they are not in the current vector. What I'm trying to achieve is finding these components using the given vector. @Anonymous

Comment: so basically 1 & 7 is not a node of your graph, the graph is a forest with two disjoint components....And if that's your definition, why not just do a simple DFS?

Comment: Isn't your problem equivalent to finding connected components in an undirected graph?

Comment: @Anonymous I agree with you, please answer it and I will upvote it :)

Comment: Still don't see how the definition in the question fits with the solution. There is no path from `4` to `6` or the other way around, yet they're supposed to be in the same component.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your definition of connected component...If that's the case

I agree with @anonymous, you can simply make the graph undirected and find the connected components using simple DFS...

I do not quite understand your original thought, at least I think the implementation will be a bit complicated, say for edges {1-->2, 2-->4, 3-->4}, 
Node #1 and #3 will be sorted at the beginning of the list, and how can you know {1,2,3,4} is a single connected component?

Anyhow, the complexity is the same with the simple DFS method, at best, which is O(V)

(If anyone think this answer is correct, please give all credits to @anonymous!)

Answer (score -1):

The way to find connected component is something like following :

```js
while(anymore_root_vertex_tostartfrom){
    vertex v=pick_a_vertex;
    remove vertex from root_vertex_list;
    initialize connected_comp_list_of_vertices;
    do a breadth_first traversal from this vertex
    keep adding the vertex you encounter in bfs to connected_comp_list_of_vertices
    of that root
}
```

I would suggest reading some more about Graph processing. Finding connected component, BFS, DFS traversal have fairly standard techniques. An excellent book on this subject is [Skiena's Algoritham Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600)

Comment: for edges {1-->2, 2-->4, 3-->4},  can this find that {1,2,3,4} are of the same component?

Comment: yes. That's what the BFS traversal will do in my psuedocode.

Comment: your BFS ignores edge direction? If I get it right...say root vertex is 1, BFS will find {1,2,4} then next root vertex is 3, which find {3}?

Comment: Here is how BFS works: It looks at immediate children first for a node which means for {1} its {2} and {3}. Then {2} and {3} are added to the list of vertex to be processed next iteration. Now {2} will find {4,5} and so on..

Comment: Are you referring to my example edges {1-->2, 2-->4, 3-->4}? Why 2 & 3 are 1's immediate children and where do 5 comes from...Sorry that if I sound dumb @@

Comment: I am referring to the diagram in the question. Its a directed graph and only one connected component in this case (as shown in the graph since starting at 1, all vertices can be reached). However the logic will work for graph with many connected components as well. Does your question pertain to a different graph?

Comment: Of course it is a different graph...it's only 3 edges with 4 nodes..I think you should be able to figure it out?

Comment: Well for any graph the pseudocode will give you connected components (and the list of vertices)

Comment: I see that the answer has been downvoted but I don't understand why. BFS, DFS and finding connected component is a standard problem in graphs which is what I presented. It has nothing to to do with one particular graph !!.